# Handling errors in C++ code of QML application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm working on a project which involves QML UI and heavy C++ logic. Most parts of our codebase use C++ exceptions for error handling. And my main question is, how can I automate translation of these C++ exceptions to QML errors?

The only relevant link I found is [Global exception handling with c++/QML](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82507/global-exception-handling-with-c-qml) which just states one needs to pass errors as return values manually. Or wrap them with try-catch blocks on QML side, again manually.

Some more details and context.

When I worked on QWidgets-based application, I could simply override [QCoreApplication::notify](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify) and handle all unhandled otherwise errors there. As for QML engine, it doesn't seem to be exception-neutral. Stack unwinding through it causes access violations and other unpleasant runtime errors. And there seems to be no extension point similar to `QCoreApplication::notify`. Closest functions `QQmlObjectOrGadget::metacall` and `static CallMethod` in `qv4qobjectwrapper.cpp:1270` are buried deep in implementation and cannot be augmented without patching Qt.

QML documentation also suggests [QJSEngine::throwError](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#throwError) as a way to produce QML exceptions from C++ code. Problem is, it requires instance of QML engine, which can be obtained through [QQmlEngine::contextForObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#contextForObject)`(...)->engine()` or [qmlEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlEngine). Which can be used only on objects handled by QML. So if you call arbitrary `Q_INVOKABLE` method on C++ object exposed to Qt, you have no easy access to `QQmlEngine` instance.

The last part, which is capturing unhandled QML exceptions, seems to be more manageable through [QQmlEngine::warnings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#warnings) signal.